# submit form to php file then to cgi script

Tags: php, forms, cgi, submit

I have a shopping cart setup with cartmanager.net

We setup a complex form, take a look (https://www.paulinameatmarket.com/?p=tasteofpaulina)

To add items to your shopping cart, the form is submited to https://www.cartmanager.net/cgi-bin/cart.cgi

With this page, i'm creating an admin page for the owner to track the ordered shipments monthly and check them off each month as they are shipped so I need to add the ordered information into a mysql database

Cartmanager doesn't have a way to send back the variables from a submitted order so I want to add the ordered item to the database before the cart.cgi script is ran. The owner will then verify that the order was actually paid, and if it wasn't he'll just delete it from the admin section.

So what I need is to have the form FIRST go to a php page, run the mysql query to insert the item info, THEN run the cart.cgi script.

This is hard to explain but i'm trying

Answer (score 0):

If the request is set as a "GET" request to cartmanager.net, you should be able to do it this way by sending it through your PHP script first and after you've inserted the data in your database doing this:

```
header('Location: https://www.cartmanager.net/cgi-bin/cart.cgi?' . $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
exit;
```

If cartmanager.net expects a "POST" request, you'd have to make the PHP script return an HTML form with all of the necessary inputs that automatically submits itself to cartmanager.net using JavaScript. I wouldn't recommend this as it not good practice and it won't work on browser with JavaScript disabled.